# Python 3.2 os module - python functions or linux commands?

Tags: python, linux

After reading http://docs.python.org/2/library/allos.html, I am a bit unclear on whether the os module contains functions that perform the same functions as system commands or if they are calling system commands. I did not see a link to the source code.

I have just started working with Python and the os module. Can someone clue me in to the nature of these functions and where I might find the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `os` module uses per-OS-specific packages, most of which use standard C calls, the same calls the command-line tools would have to use.

You want to study the  [`os.py` module source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/os.py) first, then platform-specific modules. [`posixmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Modules/posixmodule.c) handles OS calls for UNIX, OS/2 and Windows.

For example, the `os.listdir()` function uses [`opendir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir), [`readdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) and [`closedir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/closedir) calls on POSIX systems.